# Functions in a template literal

Tags: jquery, template-literals

I am making a ToDo app for a class I'm taking (and there goes another puppy), and I'm having some issue with a function actually getting called properly.

In jQuery I am appending each individual items using a Template Literal.

```
$("#taskList").append(`
                <div class="list-group-item">

                  <h4 class="list-group-item-heading ${field.completed ? 'done' : ''}">
                    ${field.task}
                  </h4>
                  <div class="buttons">
                    ${field.completed
                      ? `<div class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></div>`
                      : `<div class="complete" onclick="completeTask(${field._id})">
                          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                        </div>`
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>
              `);
```

and I have a function right after it that shows

```
function completeTask(task){
    console.log(task) // this is just for testing purposes
}
```

and I have data coming from the server that is being passed through as

```
field = {
    completed: Boolean,
    _id: String,
    task: String,
}
```

Now, every time I select the complete button, I get the following error message: 
`(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

And unfortunately, there isn't anything at (index):1, except for `<DOCTYPE html>`

Now, is this sort of thing even possible, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're missing a closing parenthesis here:

```
<div class="buttons">
  ${field.completed
```

Comment: Not quite the issue... That is the beginning of a ternary operator.



     ${field.completed
                      ? `<div class="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></div>`
                      : `<div class="complete" onclick="completeTask(${field._id})">
                          <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                        </div>`
                    }